# how to share CGImageRef to facebook using social library?

Tags: facebook, social-framework, cgimageref

> This is the method that have the image data, that image will than write to camera roll

```
CGImageRef cgImageResult = [self newSquareOverlayedImageForFeatures:features
                                                                                       inCGImage:srcImage 
                                                                                 withOrientation:curDeviceOrientation 
                                                                                                                 frontFacing:isUsingFrontFacingCamera];

                                  if (srcImage)
                            CFRelease(srcImage);

                        CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                                                    imageDataSampleBuffer, 
                                                                                    kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
                        [self writeCGImageToCameraRoll:cgImageResult withMetadata:(id)attachments];
```

Comment: [fbController addImage: i need to cgImageResult to addImage method of fbController. an hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `CGImage` to `UIImage` like so: `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:<#(CGImageRef)#>];` and post it to facebook as you have mentioned on your comments. Good Luck!

**EDIT**
Okay, do it like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageResult];
[fbController addImage:image];
```

Comment: [fbController addImage:[UIImage image]]; This is showing warning that class method +image not found(return type default to id)

Comment: You are doing it wrong way. Do it like in my example.

Comment: In take picture method i have write this.   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageResult]; and in share method that is a button i have write [fbController addImage:[UIImage image]];

Comment: kindly give me some example code to look at.

Comment: i have put the UIImage *image; into .h file and than used your answer but it is throwing exception.

Comment: 013-08-30 12:35:22.355 Mind Reader[16255:907] -[__NSCFString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed75db0
2013-08-30 12:35:22.356 Mind Reader[16255:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed75db0' these are the exceptions

Comment: I would recommend you to read some objective c programming basics.

Comment: Thanks buddy i got it worked when i called the Facebook share into take picture method instead of share method. i share method as i have mentioned earlier i got exceptions due to some release problems. thanks for your time.